# Javascript heap out of memory inserting large files with Sequelize

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I am trying to convert an excel file to MySQL; so far, it works perfectly locally. But I am using a container with 2048MB max of memory, so when I try with larger files, it does not work. I've already tried with node --max-old-space-size="1536", and it does not work. I think there has to be something in my code that causes that can be improved when inserting rows. I am using sequelize and MySQL.

```
const readXlsxFile = require("read-excel-file/node");
const db = require("../../models");
const CarteraEnRiesgo = db.carteras;
let os = require("os");
    
    const uploadExcel = async (req, res) => {
      try {
        if (!req.file) {
          return res.status(400).send("Please upload an excel file!");
        }
    
        let path = `${os.tmpdir()}/${req.file.filename}`;
    
        readXlsxFile(path)
          .then((rows) => {
            // skip header
            rows.shift();
    
            let cartera_en_riesgo = [];
    
            rows.forEach((row) => {
              let cartera = {
                id: row[0],
                FEC_CIERRE: row[1],
                SEC_CREDITO: row[2],
                MON_SALDO: row[3],
                moneda: row[4],
                VAL_TIPO_CAMBIO_CONV: row[5],
                ID_ESTADO: row[6],
                CANT_TOTAL: row[7],
                clasificacion: row[8],
              };
              cartera_en_riesgo.push(cartera);
            });
    
            CarteraEnRiesgo.bulkCreate(cartera_en_riesgo)
              .then(() => {
                res.status(200).send({
                  message: "Converted the file successfully: " + req.file.originalname,
                });
              })
              .catch((error) => {
                res.status(500).send({
                  message: "Fail to import data into database!",
                  error: error.message,
                });
              });
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
            res.status(500).send({
              message: "Could not convert the file: " + req.file.originalname,
            });
          });
      } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).send({
          message: `Could not upload the file: ${req.file.originalname}.${err}`,
        });
      }
    };
```

Comment: Depends on `read-excel-file` and how few memory leaks it has? How big is that file you're loading?

Comment: @Juan i suggest instead of loading the complete excel file into memory directly, you should be creating excel file stream and then inserting the data into MYSQL in batches.......this way you will not face heap out of memory issue.

Comment: @Gautam  Yeah, I first upload to a /tmp/ folder, and then I read the file. The file I’m trying to convert is only 7MB.

Comment: @Dominik read-excel-file works on my local computer just fine though

Comment: Well but as you pointed out yourself you got more memory to work with

Comment: @Gautam I’ll try to do it in batches and see how it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I changed from using read-excel-file as @Dominik from the comments said, and instead parsed a CSV file and insert it with `async.cargo()` to save as much memory as I could with little batches as @GautamMalik said.